# Swift Array to Set : Showing Recent Messages Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `firebase` to retrieve a list of data then convert it to an `NSDictonary` array. I want to parse the data by a property e.g `name`

```
func getAllMyModels() {
    if let e = email {
        _ = ref.child("childName").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: e).observe(.value) { snapshot in
            var dictionary = [NSDictionary]()
            let children = snapshot.children
            while let rest = children.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value {
                dictionary.append(NSDictionary(dictionary: value as! [String: Any]))
            }
            let names = dictionary.flatMap {$0["name"]} // names print correct values
            let set = Set(names)
            print(set)
        }
    }
}
```

This code can't be complied the error is:

```
Showing Recent Messages
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

If i removed this line:

```
let set = Set(Array(names))
```

all works fine.

I also tested by replace it by this block

```
  let ar = ["name1","name2"].flatMap { return $0 }
  Set(ar)
```

No errors.

Not sure why? Who can tell, thanks!

**EDIT**: Even though the element in the array is `String` type but the names array is `[Any]`, so the solution is

```
  let names = dictionary.flatMap {$0["name"]} as! [String]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this errors occurs because the Array you generate from the dictionary with flatMap is an Array of Any and not a String Array, try to cast to a String like this:

```
...
let names = dictionary.flatMap {$0["name"] as? String} 
let set = Set(Array(names))
...
```

Hope this help you

Comment: NO. $0["name"] is ```String``` type.

Answer (score 0):

Cast `names` to `[String]`:

```
let names = dictionary.flatMap {$0["name"]} as! [String]
```